# Listing Only SubFolders In C#?

Tags: c#, directory, visual-c#-express-2010

I have some code:

```
string pathUser = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
string pathDownload = Path.Combine(pathUser, @"documents\iracing\setups\");
DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(pathDownload); // Populates field with all Sub Folders
FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.sto");
foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
{
     listBox2.Items.Add(file.Name);
}
```

I want the subFolders of: `documents\iracing\setups\` to be shown, not the files...including the .sto files. All i need is to list the Subfolders....i have no idea how to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can try this:

```
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(pathDownload);
DirectoryInfo[] directories = directory.GetDirectories();

foreach(DirectoryInfo folder in directories)
     listBox2.Items.Add(folder.Name);
```

Comment: how would i do it to populate my listbox2 with these subfolders?

Answer (score 2):

Just use this function

```
string pathUser = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
string pathDownload = Path.Combine(pathUser, @"documents\iracing\setups\");
DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(pathUser); // Populates field with all Sub Folders
DirectoryInfo[] directorys = dinfo.GetDirectories();
foreach (DirectoryInfo directory in directorys)
{
    listBox2.Items.Add(directory.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`EnumerateDirectories`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratedirectories.aspx) or [`GetDirectories`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.getdirectories.aspx) instead of `GetFiles` if you wish to get... directories.

Comment: So, what do i put inside the ()'s? : FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetDirectories();

Comment: @EliteGamer - Did you read the links? You really need to learn to read documentation. The return type and needed parameters (if any) are listed.