# c# - How to put each zip file from source folder to target folder using 7z function

Tags: winforms, textbox, filepath, 7zip, filesystemwatcher

I have a `window form`, which contains two buttons to let a user choose the `input directory` and `output directory` like below. In addition, I have a `fileSystemWatcher` to monitor the empty source folder and `timer` to use with the zip function. The user can select a directory (which contain some sub-folder) and click `start` to create a zip file, and they can put that zip file to any directories from their preference.

[image]

the result will be like this

[image]

However, I failed to create the zip file to the selected directory using 7zip, neither the naming matches the subdirectory from the source folder. Below is my code to process the zip function using 7zip.

```
string source = textBoxInput.Text + "\\*";
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(textBoxInput.Text, "*.7z", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
string target = tBoxOutput.Text + "\\everySingleZipFile"; // the target location only contains zip file from the source location

foreach (var file in files)
{
  // process zip for every file, no idea how to implement it.
  _sevenZip.CreateZipFile(source, target);
}
```

Here is my 7z method

```
public void CreateZipFile(string sourceName, string targetName)
{
    ProcessStartInfo zipProcess = new ProcessStartInfo();
    zipProcess.FileName = @"E:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"; // select the 7zip program to start
    zipProcess.Arguments = "a -t7z \"" + targetName + "\" \"" + sourceName + "\" -mx=9";
    zipProcess.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
    Process zip = Process.Start(zipProcess);
    zip.WaitForExit();
}
```

This is the button for the user to choose which directory to put the zip file.

```
private void btnOutput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        fbd.Description = $"Choose an output path";

        if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // show the path in the text box
            tBoxOutput.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;
        }
    }
```

Comment: when you say "output " you mean extract?

Comment: output directory? then what about output fileName? Because .7z is file not directory

Comment: @DorLugasi No, only to move the zip file to other directory based on users preference if they don't want the zip file in the same directory.

Comment: @Patty_Putty so you have an existing file of zip and you want to move it?
or you have an existing folder and you want to archive it to a specific location?

Comment: @Patty_Putty I've edited my answer for you

Comment: @DorLugasi thanks for helping, I've added the button event, which is for the user to choose any directory to move the zip file to. I also added more detail to explain my problem. Your answer is similar to what I done before, I think I done wrong in that button event.

Comment: @Patty_Putty Look at my answer now, after editing again

Comment: @DorLugasi  have tried your suggestion but the zip file remains in the same folder once the time lapsed for zipping process. I wonder the 7z method I use is correct in this way. Here is my whole code. You can review my code [here](https://rextester.com/WWQKN57068)

Comment: In my Answer there's a working Code for creating a 7zip as your question asked for, I don't know about this SevenZip class, and your question is not about that class either.

Comment: @DorLugasi I only can't do is move/copy the zip file to another selected directory. Perhaps I miss something to check between the root-folder and sub-folder before executing the zip process.

Comment: again. use my code...

Comment: @DorLugasi the zip file name must same as the sub-directory that being zipped. Perhaps I edited the title could make it understandable.

Comment: that's a simple change, from file dialog browser to directory browser, iv'e edited my answer again for you. if it was helpful,mark as answer

Comment: @DorLugasi thanks, I forgot to mention that the zip file to the output location will be more than one, and the zip file name should be the same as each subdirectory. your suggestion is very close, but I might need to output the zip file name dynamically from each subdirectory.

Comment: that would just add a simple for-each loop and to edit the input folder from
c:/path/path/folder to c:/path/path/folder/subfolder1
you can get that easily with the for-each loop, take a look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10668520/9615185

Comment: @DorLugasi, I don't need the zip file name shown in the output location in the textbox though, and not sure why the zip file always on the desktop location.

Comment: so what is the use of the output text box ?
and the zip file is on the desktop because of that's what you choose.
if you used my code the, output file should be where ever you choose in the  FolderBrowserDialog.

Comment: by the way you can't ask a question, edit it and add a lot of things to the question on the go, while people answer your question. and you mark as "correct answer" and then add more stuff you need to do, and remove the "correct answer". that's just rude.

Comment: @DorLugasi, i edited my code. In this program, users don't need manually type the name for zip file in the output textbox. They choose the output location for each zip file only. I knew something wrong with the source path and target path in that causing the issue and still try to fix it.

Comment: you don't write the path in the text box, it is filled with the path you chose in the folderBrowserDialog.

Comment: @DorLugasi, but it does not require to put the `directoryName + ".7z"` in the `folderBrowserDialog` because the source folder is empty at the beginning and it is just check if any file/folder exists. Then it starts to zip each subfolder to the target folder with its name.

Comment: again, you cannot change your question so many times and then remove the "correct answer" from an answer that was helpful for your described question.
I was trying to help you. and did exactly as you described 3-4 times.
look at how many edits on your question! 15!!!!

also, I commented above how you should do the subfolder thing and even inserted a link that could help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

the main problem you have is choosing a directory as an output instead of a file.

I made a screen similar to yours

[image]

after choosing directories for output and input

[image]
the code for the browse button events:

```
private void btnBrowseInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
    {
        DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fbd.SelectedPath))
        {
            txtInput.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;
        }
    }

}

private void btnBrowseOutput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtInput.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please choose an input folder first");
            return;
        }
        using (var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
        {
            DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();

            if (result == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fbd.SelectedPath))
            {
                var directoryName = Path.GetFileName(txtInput.Text);
                txtOutput.Text = Path.Combine(fbd.SelectedPath, directoryName + ".7z");
            }
        }

}
```

and the code for the zip button event:

```
string zipProgramPath = @"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnZip_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtInput.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtOutput.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Choose input directory and output file");
            }
            else
            {
                CreateZipFile(txtInput.Text, txtOutput.Text);
            }
        }
        public void CreateZipFile(string sourceName, string targetName)
        {
            try
            {
                ProcessStartInfo zipProcess = new ProcessStartInfo();
                zipProcess.FileName = zipProgramPath; // select the 7zip program to start
                zipProcess.Arguments = "a -t7z \"" + targetName + "\" \"" + sourceName + "\" -mx=9";
                zipProcess.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
                zipProcess.UseShellExecute = true;
                Process zip = Process.Start(zipProcess);
                zip.WaitForExit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I'm not trying to extract it. Just "store" it to other folder based on user preference.

Comment: My apology. Assume the input directory have some subfolders (with file) to be zipped and user can also have a choice to have that zip file directly created in other directory instead of move or copy to different location.

Comment: the updated answer gets all the input destination folders and files and archives them in a new destination as the user wants.

Comment: if my answer was helpful for you please vote up and mark answer, if not then tell me whats wrong